# Input pipeline w/ keras.utils.Sequence object or tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

I am currently using a `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` object to generate image batches for a CNN. I am using Tensorflow 2.2 and the `Model.fit` method for the model.  When I fit the model, the following warning is thrown in each epoch when I set `use_multiprocessing=True` in `tf.keras.model.fit(...)`:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow,
 causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended
```

The model is optimizing just fine, as expected from the docs and the fact that I am using a `Sequence`-based generator. But if `use_multiprocessing` is going to be a deprecated functionality in lieu of `tf.data` objects, I would like to be using the most up-to-date input pipeline. I currently use the following `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`-based generator inspired by this article on good practices for partitioning large datasets:
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
'Generates data for Keras'
def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, data_dir, batch_size=32, dim=(128,128), n_channels=1,
             n_classes=2, shuffle=True, **augmentation_kwargs):
    'Initialization'
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.labels = labels
    self.list_IDs = list_IDs
    self.data_dir = data_dir
    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()
    self.augmentor = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(**augmentation_kwargs)

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):

        # Store sample
        X[i,] = np.load(self.data_dir +'/{}_stars.npy'.format(ID))

        # Store class
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]

    # Reshape and apply augmentation to sample
    X,y = self.augmentor.flow(X.reshape(self.batch_size,*self.dim,1),y=y,
                              shuffle=False,batch_size=self.batch_size)[0]

    return X, y
```

All data from all classes is in the `data_dir` directory and are stored as individual `.npy` files. The IDs come from a list of strings. The class labels are taken from a dictionary whose keys are the IDs -- as in the article.

I really like the intuition of the `Sequence` generator set-up. I can also easily generator random batches to check that it is behaving as I would expect. But how can I reproduce this set-up with `tf.data`? How do I reproduce the multiprocessing batch generation of a `Sequence` generator with the `interleave` and `prefetch` methods of `tf.data.Dataset`? And/or can I simply ingest this `Sequence`-based generator with the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` method?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

may be to late to answer, but that what I did and it's work fine for me;
1- my class was like that;

```
class DataGen(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, df, sr=8000, seconds=3, batch_size=16, shuffle=True):
        self.files = np.array(df.filepath)
        self.label = np.array(df.label)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.sr = sr
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.dim = self.sr*self.seconds
        self.on_epoch_end()
    
    def __len__():
        return len(self.label)//self.batch_size
    
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        indexs = self.indexs[np.arange(x, x+self.batch_size)]
        return self.__getBatch__(indexs)
        
    def __getBatch__(self, indexs):
        X, y = [], []
        for i in indexs:
            wav = self.__loadFile__(self.files[i])
            X.append(librosa.feature.mfcc(wav, self.sr).T)
            y.append(self.label[i])
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(X), to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)
        
    def __loadFile__(self, file):
        y, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=8000, mono=True)
        if len(y)>self.dim:
            return y[:self.dim]
        return np.pad(y, (0, self.dim-len(y)), 'constant', constant_values=0)
        
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexs = np.arange(len(self.label))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexs)
```

2- than I change to a function like follow;

```
def gen(sr=8000, seconds=3, batch_size=16, shuffle=True):
    dim = sr*seconds
    def loadFile(file):
        wav, _ = librosa.load(file, sr=sr, mono=True)
        if len(wav)>dim:
            return wav[:dim]
        return np.pad(wav, (0, dim-len(wav)), 'constant', constant_values=0)
    
    while True:
        indexs = np.arange(len(df))
        if shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(indexs)
        
        for x in range(len(df)//batch_size):
            X, y = [], []
            for i in indexs[np.arange(x*batch_size, (x+1)*batch_size)]:
                X.append(librosa.feature.mfcc(loadFile(df.filepath[i]), sr).T)
                y.append(df.label[i])
                
            yield tf.convert_to_tensor(X), to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)
```

3- and works fine:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.dtypes.float32, tf.dtypes.int32))
```

Comment: This is far more helpful than the official documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am currently facing a similar issue and while my generator works fine without multiprocessing, it is very slow. Is your solution safe to use ? no issues with data overlapping when using multiprocessing and workers?

Comment: I have just figured out somthing may help, in the class you can add a function `__call__(self)` in it you should put the code that will return the data as generator and you can just give the class object to the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`,  note that I haven't test it,

Comment: @WalidBousseta Were you able to use __call__(self) to any success?

Comment: @Austin yes I have test it and it's work fine, inside the `__call__()` I'm callingthe get_item function

Answer (score 2):

here's another method that I use with tensorflow and it's workes fine:

```
class DataGen():
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size=32, shuffle=True):
        self.data = np.array(df)
        self.indexs = np.arange(self.data.shape[0])
        if shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexs)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]//self.batch_size
    
    def get_item(self, x):
        # data preprocessing
        data, label = self.data[x]
        return data, label
    
    def __call__(self):
        for i in self.indexs:
            yield self.get_item(i)
    
train_gen = DataGen(train_df)
types = (tf.float32, tf.int32)
shapes = ((1, 500, 201), (n_classes))
batch_size = 32
train_data = Dataset.from_generator(train_gen, output_types=types, output_shapes=shapes)
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)

# test
X, y = next(iter(train_data))
print(X.shape, y.shape)
```

Comment: @Austin here I have used the __call__() method and worked fine

Comment: @Waild do we need to make class Datagen inherit Sequence?

Comment: @GPatel no need I didn't use it